# Как узнать версию CompileSDKVersion?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Создаю впервые андроид приложение вот по этому уроку: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJpN1ostdiY
этот парень пишет версию CompileSDKVersion 26 а также buildToolsVersion 26.0.0 но как узнать какая у меня версия ? я работаю в Eclipse использую Gluon plugin.

Comment: Вы сначала узнайте, что это такое. После этого вопрос отпадет. Звучит сейчас как "Этот парень живет в Самаре. Как узнать, где живу я?"

Comment: обычно указывается последний стабильный API, сегодня это 28

Comment: Спасибо большое.